# kotlin: check if a class is object class?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a kotlin object and a java class like:

KotlinObject.kt

```
object KotlinObject{
....
}
```

JavaClass.java

```
class JavaClass {
...
}
```

and a kotlin function to check:

```
fun foo(cls: Class<*>): Any {
   if (cls is kotlin's object) { //how to do this?
      return ?  //wanna return object's instance
   } else {
      return cls.newInstance()
   }    
}
```

I can pass kotlin object or java class to this function:

```
foo(KotlinObject::class.java)
foo(JavaClass::class.java)
```

so is it possible to tell which one is kotlin's object?

Comment: Do you have to pass the java version of each object?  Could you pass KotlinObject::class and JavaClass::class?  Or maybe even the types themselves.  I just have a feeling that once you do the '.java' thing, you've stripped away a lot of the metadata associated with each "object".

Comment: The only way you "assume" it an object class, is to check if it has a static `INSTANCE` field, but it doesn't give you 100% sure answer. If you add a static field `INSTANCE` to a regular java class, you would get a false positive.
Nevertheless it all sounds very sketchy... can you share some more details on why you need that? I have a feeling you're overthinking something.

Comment: Just wondering, what's the point in knowing if something is an object or a class?

Comment: @Steve "I just have a feeling that once you do the '.java' thing, you've stripped away a lot of the metadata associated with each "object"" No, there is a way to transform it back into a `KClass`: `.kotlin` extension property.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - ah.  Good to know!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Alexey Romanov for pointing out in the comments that the Kotlin  class information is available from `Class<*>`.

```
fun foo(cls: Class<*>) {
    if (cls.kotlin.objectInstance != null)
        println("KotlinObject")
    else
        println("Other class")
}
```

My original approach was to mimic Kotlins `KClass.objectInstance`.

I keep this for reference but please use the solution above.

```
fun foo(cls: Class<*>) {
    val objectInstance = cls.declaredFields.firstOrNull {
        it.type == cls && it.name == "INSTANCE"
    }

    if (objectInstance != null)
        println("KotlinObject")
    else
        println("Other class")
}
```

Be aware that any Java Singleton using the name 'INSTANCE' for the singleton field will also be reported as Kotlin object in that case.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.  He doesn't want to know when he has an instance of JavaClass or KotlinObject.  Rather, I think he wants to be able to tell if an arbitrary type is a class type or an object.  That's the way I read it anyway. - in other words, 'foo' needs to work without knowing of the existence of JavaClass and KotlinObject.

Comment: Good point. So the example has to be foo(KotlinObject()) and foo(JavaClass())

Comment: ...actually...NO.  He wants to test the Types, not objects based on the types.  That's a valid thing because everything in Kotlin is an object.  No need to instantiate them. - If you instantiate them, you're just going to turn around and do x.getClass() and y.getClass(), right?

Comment: the question has been updated, I hope it's more clear.

Comment: Updated my answer in order to match the updated question.

Comment: Me too!  Short answer...defining JavaClass in a Java file is fine. Still works.

Comment: Or, `cls.kotlin.objectInstance` :)

Comment: Right! Was not aware of that. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

```
object KotlinObject{}
class JavaClass {}

fun foo(cls: KClass<*>) {
    if (cls.objectInstance != null)
        println("It's a Kotlin object")
    else
        println("It's NOT a Kotlin object")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    foo(KotlinObject::class)
    foo(JavaClass::class)
}
```

Output:

```
It's a Kotlin object
It's NOT a Kotlin object
```

If, for some reason, you must pass the Java class, then I couldn't figure out any way to do this.  I think all the distinction is then gone.

NOTE: This works even if JavaClass is defined in a Java file.  Every object in Kotlin is of a KClass type regardless of how and where it was defined.  That is, ::class works on any object in Kotlin.

Comment: Actually JavaClass is a java class, so I don't think we can pass a java class as KClass. I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This works fine for me even if JavaClass is defined in Java.  <object>::class in Kotlin is always a KClass.  If it weren't, you couldn't then add ".java" because that's a construct defined in KClass.